# Python face recognition algorithm does not run loops properly and skips them

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, optimization

> (Before I start, I am not sure if this post belongs to here, so
>   instead of downvoting please give feedback so I can ask it in a better
>   place)

Recently, I got interested in image recognition so I downloaded OpenCV and pther libraries and started coding a simple system that logs people entering my room into a mySQL database. Which at first worked fine. But then, I accidentally broke the linux partition of my laptop. So I backed the files up and reinstalled the system. However, after reinstalling the code stopped working.It just ... didn't work. And the most frustrating part was that I was not getting any errors. It just didn't do what it was supposed to do. I add the problematic part of the code below. However, I added the full version at the end of the question just incase...

```
while (b < 9):
        ret, img =cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
            gray,
            scaleFactor = 1.2,
            minNeighbors = 5,
            minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
            )

        if (len(faces) != 0 ):
            b+=1
            for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x , y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

                id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])


        # Check if confidence is less them 100 ==> "0" is perfect match 


                confidence = 100 - confidence

                conf_list.append(confidence)
                id_list.append(id)


                if (b ==8):
                    confidence = max(conf_list)
                    id = id_list[conf_list.index(confidence)]
                    a = id
                    id = names[id]


                    if (confidence > 40.0):

                        Confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(confidence))

                        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user_info_basic WHERE user_id="+str(a))
                        print('\n')
                        print(Confidence)


                        for row in cur.fetchall():
                            print (row[0])
                            print (row[1])
                            print (row[2])
                            print (row[3])
                            print (row[4])

                        db.close()

                        for i in range(1,1000000):
                            if not (os.path.exists("/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User/User." + str(a) + "." + str(i) + ".jpg")):
                                cv2.imwrite("/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User/User." + str(a) + "." + str(i) + ".jpg",gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                                train()
                                return 0

                    else:


                        first_name = raw_input("First Name=")
                        last_name = raw_input("Last Name=")
                        email = raw_input("Email=")
                        TC_No = raw_input("TC=")

                        if (email == None):
                            email = NULL

                        if (TC_No == None):
                            TC_No = NULL


                        names.append(first_name)

                        with open('/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/users.txt' , 'w') as f:
                        for n in names:
                            f.write(n + '\n')


                        for i in range(1,1000000):
                            if not (os.path.exists("/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User/User." + str(i) + ".1.jpg")):   
                                a = i
                                cur.execute("INSERT INTO `ankarvyd_YKBilsem`.`user_info_basic` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `TC_No`) VALUES (" + a + first_name + last_name + email + TC_No + ")")
                                db.close()
                                cam.release()
                                photo(i)
                                train()
                                return 0
```

Ok so, the code is supposed to work, I see no reason that it should not. I have checked the tabbing **twice**. And even deleted all the tabs and readded them from scratch(after a backup of course). I have no idea what causes this. It recognizes a face that I added before and gives me info. But when it does not recognize a face, it just ends the program. I hope that you can see something I did not see. Here is the full version of the code.(the database data is changed)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os 
import pickle
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="0.0.0.0",  
                     user="user", 
                     passwd="password", 
                     db="db") 

cur = db.cursor()

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "/home/yigido/Downloads/opencv-3.4.0/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#iniciate id counter
id = 0
# names related to ids: example ==> Marcelo: id=1,  etc




names = []
conf_list=[]
id_list=[]







# Define min window size to be recognized as a face

def train():

    # Path for face image database
    path = '/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User' 


    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/yigido/Downloads/opencv-3.4.0/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");

    # function to get the images and label data
    def getImagesAndLabels(path):

        imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
        faceSamples=[]
        ids = []

        for imagePath in imagePaths:

            PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
            img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

            id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])

            faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                ids.append(id)

        return faceSamples,ids

    print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
    faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
    recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

    # Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
    recognizer.write('/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

    # Print the numer of faces trained and end program
    print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))


def photo(x):

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cam.set(3, 640) # set video widht
    cam.set(4, 480) # set video height

    # For each person, enter one numeric face id
    face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/yigido/Downloads/opencv-3.4.0/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml')

    face_id = x

    print("\n [INFO] Initializing face capture. Look the camera and wait ...")
    # Initialize individual sampling face count
    count = 0

    while(True):

        ret, img = cam.read()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:

            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)     
            count += 1

            # Save the captured image into the datasets folder
            cv2.imwrite("/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User/User." + str(face_id) + "." + str(count) + ".jpg",  gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])


        k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
        if k == 27:
            break
        elif count >= 30: # Take 30 face sample and stop video
             break

    # Do a bit of cleanup
    print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():

    with open('/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/users.txt' , 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            names.append(line.strip())

    b = 0
    # Initialize and start realtime video capture
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cam.set(3, 640) # set video widht
    cam.set(4, 480) # set video height

    # Define min window size to be recognized as a face
    minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
    minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)

    while (b < 9):
        ret, img =cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
            gray,
            scaleFactor = 1.2,
            minNeighbors = 5,
            minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
            )

        if (len(faces) != 0 ):
            b+=1
            for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x , y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

                id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])


        # Check if confidence is less them 100 ==> "0" is perfect match 


                confidence = 100 - confidence

                conf_list.append(confidence)
                id_list.append(id)


                if (b ==8):
                    confidence = max(conf_list)
                    id = id_list[conf_list.index(confidence)]
                    a = id
                    id = names[id]


                    if (confidence > 40.0):

                        Confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(confidence))

                        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user_info_basic WHERE user_id="+str(a))
                        print('\n')
                        print(Confidence)


                        for row in cur.fetchall():
                            print (row[0])
                            print (row[1])
                            print (row[2])
                            print (row[3])
                            print (row[4])

                        db.close()

                        for i in range(1,1000000):
                            if not (os.path.exists("/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User/User." + str(a) + "." + str(i) + ".jpg")):
                                cv2.imwrite("/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User/User." + str(a) + "." + str(i) + ".jpg",gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                                train()
                                return 0

                    else:


                        first_name = raw_input("First Name=")
                        last_name = raw_input("Last Name=")
                        email = raw_input("Email=")
                        TC_No = raw_input("TC=")

                        if (email == None):
                            email = NULL

                        if (TC_No == None):
                            TC_No = NULL


                        names.append(first_name)

                        with open('/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/users.txt' , 'w') as f:
                        for n in names:
                            f.write(n + '\n')


                        for i in range(1,1000000):
                            if not (os.path.exists("/home/yigido/projects/face_recognition/dataset/User/User." + str(i) + ".1.jpg")):   
                                a = i
                                cur.execute("INSERT INTO `ankarvyd_YKBilsem`.`user_info_basic` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `TC_No`) VALUES (" + a + first_name + last_name + email + TC_No + ")")
                                db.close()
                                cam.release()
                                photo(i)
                                train()
                                return 0











main()
    # Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
```

Comment: Read: [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)]  Set a breakpoint after image capture in your code, present an apple to the camera, debug it. There are too many things in your code that make not much sense w/o the getup you have and frankly for poking around in the code - it is (4 me) simply too long: See  [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: However, İ cant use make a minimum verifiable complete example because I have no idea what is causing the error. It could anything from tabs to an error depending on the compiler. So I think providing the full code would be more effective

Comment: No. Debugging your own code would be most effective. Did you try that?